# padding/margin when using <Text> inside for loop

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am creating multiple `Text` using for loop, but i have seen some unnecessary padding when i am using this approach.

```
render(){
    var child = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        child.push(<Text key={index}> {index}</Text >)
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                {child}
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text>0</Text>
                <Text>1</Text>
                <Text>2</Text>
                <Text>3</Text>
                <Text>4</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Output :

[image]

As you can observe the `Text` which i have added through for loop is leaving some space between two `Text`, but if i write it streight 5 times, it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing something at this time. There is a space in your loop.

```
child.push(<Text key={index}> {index}</Text >)
```

change to that

```
child.push(<Text key={index}>{index}</Text >)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the extra spacing before `{index}`  :)

```
<Text key={index}>{index}</Text >
```